# Confused with input/output streams for a proxy

Tags: java, proxy, stream

Attempting to code a very simple, bare bones threaded HTTP proxy server in Java, and 
I've made good progress:

1. The client connects to the server, input and output
   streams to the client are made
2. The target URL is extracted from the GET request
3. A connection is made with the target web server, and an inputstream is established

Now I understand I need to send the data coming in from the server inputstream and forward
it to the client outputstream, but how to exactly do this escapes me.  The extend of my experience
with input and output streams has been sending single Strings, and I don't quite have a solid
understanding of how exactly these streams work.

Am I supposed to read all the data from the inputstream into a file, and then write to the output stream?  Is there a more elegant solution?

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Proxy {

/////////////////////////////////////
public static void go(){

int incomingport = 50000;
ServerSocket myproxysocket = null;

try{
myproxysocket = new ServerSocket(incomingport);
while(true){
System.out.println("HTTP Java Proxy Server");
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Listening on port 50000...Press CTRL+C to exit");
System.out.println();
Socket client = myproxysocket.accept();
Thread t = new Thread(new ClientHandler(client));
t.start();
}//end while
}//end try

catch(Exception E){
E.printStackTrace();    
}
}//end method go()

///////////////////////////////////
public static void main(String args[]) {

Proxy myserver =  new Proxy();
myserver.go();

}//end main
}//end class proxy


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class ClientHandler implements Runnable{

private final DataInputStream clientin;
private final DataOutputStream clientout;
private final Socket clientSocket;


//constructor----------------
public ClientHandler(Socket incomingSocket) throws IOException{

clientSocket = incomingSocket; 
clientin = new DataInputStream(incomingSocket.getInputStream());
clientout = new DataOutputStream(incomingSocket.getOutputStream());


}//--------------------------

////////////////////
public void run(){
try{

//Get URL from client
String getrequestline = clientin.readLine();
String targetURL = null;
String clientIP = null;
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(getrequestline);
st.nextToken();
targetURL = st.nextToken();
clientIP = clientSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString();
System.out.println();
System.out.println("IP: " + clientIP);
System.out.println("Requested URL: " + targetURL);
System.out.println();

//connect to target URL
URL url = new URL(targetURL);
URLConnection targetconnection = url.openConnection();
targetconnection.setDoInput(true);
targetconnection.setDoOutput(false);


InputStream is = targetconnection.getInputStream();

//How do I read in from is and write out to clientout?

//clientout.write(???????)

}//try
catch(Exception E){
 E.printStackTrace();
}//catch
finally{
try{clientSocket.close();}
catch(Exception ee){}
}//finally
}//end run----------

}//end CLASS--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very neat Utility class in

```
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
```

thats from the commons-io package. use it if you can. otherwise, a simple approach (not using any NIO stuff) would be this:

```
public static void copy(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    byte[] buff = new byte[1024*1024];
    int a = 0;
    while((a = is.read(buff)) > -1) {

        // a is the number of bytes ACTUALLY read, so 
        // when we write, that's the number of bytes to write
        os.write(buff,0,a);
    }
    os.flush();
}
```

and, as usual, don't forget to flush.

Comment: Thank you!.  If buff is a byte array, what exactly is being sent between the two streams?  Is it not HTML?

Comment: when, for example, a JSP generates HTML on the server, it can set it's character encoding (or use the default). this character encoding is then used to transform the text (which might contain multi-byte characters such as "你好") into a stream of bytes. in the HTTP header, the server also tells the client which encoding it used, so that the client can convert it back to actual characters. in between, it is just a bunch of bytes, much like "<html>".getBytes("utf-8"); would give you an array of 6 bytes, but "你好“.getBytes("utf-8") would give you an array of 6 bytes. 你好 is "hello" in chinese

Comment: 2 characters, that actually (in utf-8) translate to 6 bytes. since your proxy doesn't have to know about the actual characters (it doesn't have to display them), you can just copy raw bytes. if you want to know about the characters, you would have to read the headers, find out the character encoding, decode the bytes, then do the same again (send header on the other side, then encode the characters to bytes using the same character encoding.

Comment: One more question:  The ports used to connect to the proxy keep climbing up from 50,000, even after restarting the proxy.  Currently it's up to port 62,000 or so.  Is there a socket I need to close?

Comment: if you restart the proxy, i.e. when the the VM exits, these SHOULD be freed automatically.

Comment: note that you should NOT create a new ServerSocket every time you succesfully accepted a connection. just accept again:

Comment: serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            while(isListening) {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                Thread connectionThread = new ConnectionThread(this, socket);
                connectionThread.start();
            }